# I need to replace in the_content & the_title with a string

Tags: wordpress

I need to replace the_content & the_title with a custom text (for example "hello world") every time I write "Alert" on my WYSIWYG.

So When I write ALERT on my editor, in the front I will see instead the_content "Hello world" and in the_title as well.

the thing is that when I edit my text and replace ALERT I need the title remains with the "Hello world" text.

Thanks

Comment: Your looking for shortcode

Comment: I need a function to do this, and if I edit the text I need the custom text remains in the title

Comment: You mean when you find text then replace with another

Answer (score 0):

[image]Adding this PHP snippet to the functions.php of your wordpress theme will allow you to replace keywords within the_content and the_excerpt using an associative array.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'vv_modify_post_title',99 );
function vv_modify_post_title( $title ) {
    $replace = array(
        // 'WORD TO REPLACE' => 'REPLACE WORD WITH THIS'
        'Alert' => 'hello world',
    );
    $title = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $title);
    return $title;
}

function replace_text_wps($text){
    $replace = array(
        // 'WORD TO REPLACE' => 'REPLACE WORD WITH THIS'
        'Alert' => 'hello world',
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps',99);
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_text_wps',99);
```

Comment: I think this part is not working:

add_filter( 'the_title', 'suppress_if_blurb', 10, 2 );

Comment: Yes I just replace with function name

Comment: It is working on the_content but not in the title. :(

Comment: https://wpshout.com/quick-guides/changing-wordpress-post-titles-appear-first-filter-hook-tutorial/

Comment: please add title here

Comment: Still not working, it only changes the_content, Don't know why doesn´t changes the title

Comment: check with default theme. This is right code what you want.

Comment: Im working on twentyseventeen theme, Tried in the twentysixteen with the same result....

Comment: where you adding this code? You need to add in function.php

Comment: Yes I know, it's placed in functions.php I tried in other themes, but it's not working, any idea why?? thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please deactive all plugin and check

Comment: Working for me as we discussed

Comment: I have updated code please check path /wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/functions.php

Comment: Ok I see, Probably it's my fault because of my english. I need to add to the_title the custom text, not replace it. And If I change in the editor the word Alert, I need the_title to remains the same: "Hello world + the_title" Sorry I can't explain myself better.

Comment: And the custom text it's only added to the editor, not to the Title in the backend.